# C# Unity game test

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender, cube, box

I'm currently trying to get a game working in unity via C#. I think I did a good job to this point.

The game is a stacker Game:

A box will move from left to right and you press space to stack it
If it's on the last box you placed its going further.

But now my problem is: the box is an object made in Blender.

But I want the boxes I'm creating underneath the current box the player is controlling to look like the box I made in Blender.

How can I achieve this? To this point I just use:

```
    GameObject cb = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    cb.transform.position = new Vector3(CurrentX, CurrentY, CurrentZ);
```

to create a normal cube.

Comment: You probably need a prefab, google how they work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that 2 lines of code can do everything you just mentioned. Hopefully, that's just a snippet from your code.

> But now my problem is: the box is an object made in Blender.
>
> But I want the boxes I'm creating underneath the current box the
>   player is controlling to look like the box I made in Blender.

You have to export the box from Blender to `.fbx`, `.blend` or any other 3D model format that is supported in Unity. You can then import that file you exported into Unity. [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html) is a tutorial for that.

Make that imported cube/GameObject into a **prefab** then use the `Instantiate` function to create new cube each time instead of `GameObject.CreatePrimitive`.

Change your current code to

```
public GameObject boxPrfab;
GameObject cb = Instantiate(boxPrfab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
cb.transform.position = new Vector3(CurrentX, CurrentY, CurrentZ);
```

Make sure to drag that prefab into the `boxPrfab` slot.

Comment: thanks for the help, but iam left with one problem : i did it just like you said, but now there are muttliple boxes and ground-planes when i press space...there shouldnt be that much clones of the box and they are all out of place...is there a way to include pictures in here?

Comment: i think i forgot to metion that i dont want the new cubes i create to execute code...i just want them to look like my object...is there maybe a easier way of doing it ? or is it the best way to do that ?

Comment: You do not have enough reputation to upload picture here. You can upload the picture on imgur.com then provide the url here in your question. As for your problem, I don't understand what problem you are having now. As long as the code inn your questions works, the one in my question should work for you.

Comment: If it doesn't work, feel free to upload the working project somewhere then upload the non working project that uses my script. Provide link to both of them here and I will check the working project, see how it works then check the non working one and figure out what's wrong with it. I think this is the easiest way to solve your problem as it is currently hard for me to understand it.

Comment: here is my problem http://imgur.com/a/MillY btw, this uses your code ._.

Comment: I am sorry that I can't still understand what's going on even with those images. Probably can help you I have access to the working and non working project.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `box` `GameObject` that you want to spawn already exists in the scene. Then create a `Prefab` in the `Project` tab by right-clicking into the tab and selecting `Create` -> `Prefab`. Name the prefab something sensitive like e. g. `BoxPrefab`. Now drag'n'drop the `box` `GameObject` from the `Hierarchy` tab into the `Project` tab onto the newly created prefab entry.

Now you can add a public member variable to the script that is to instantiate the box spawns, e. g. like this:

```
public GameObject PrefabBox = null;
```

Then drag'n'drop the prefab entry that you created before from the `Project` tab onto that new property `PrefabBox` in the `Inspector` tab. In that same script you can instantiate spawns of the prefab e. g. by the following code:

```
GameObject boxSpawn = GameObject.Instantiate<GameObject>(
    PrefabBox,
    new Vector3(CurrentX, CurrentY, CurrentZ),
    PrefabBox.transform.rotation);
```

[Find more info on instantiating GameObjects dynamically in the Unity3d docs.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html)

[Find the syntax of GameObject.Instantiate here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)